# Cannot access protected property - Laravel 5.7 - Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm currently trying to put together Laravel site that can communicate via PHP Docker library to perform some basic docker tasks. Most things i have muddled though but I'm hitting an issue when trying to display a list of images in an index blade.

Error thrown :

```
Cannot access protected property Docker\API\Model\ImageSummary::$id (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/admin/images/index.blade.php)
```

In the controller I have :

```
public function index()
{
  $docker = Docker::create();
  $params=array("all"=>true);
  $images = $docker->imageList();
  return view('admin/images.index')->with(compact ('images'));
}
```

In the blade I then attempt to populate a table with :

```
<tbody>
<td>
@foreach ($images as $image)
{{$image->id}}
@endforeach
</td>
</tbody>
```

Vardump run on the blade for $images displays :

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(Docker\API\Model\ImageSummary)#990 (10) { ["id":protected]=> string(71) "sha256:657d7ae3892e0bf35bb240af7e81089788f74fd7ad9ab0f72fbfa6f274fcf6cc" ["parentId":protected]=> string(71) "sha256:e239fd404f67adb024ea61b9b1d16dae476a968d5dcd073e284a462fe9fcc356" ["repoTags":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "zmsbase:20180901-151007" [1]=> string(14) "zmsbase:latest" } ["repoDigests":protected]=> NULL ["created":protected]=> int(1535811082) ["size":protected]=> int(297427932) ["sharedSize":protected]=> int(-1) ["virtualSize":protected]=> int(297427932) ["labels":protected]=> NULL ["containers":protected]=> int(-1) } [1]=> object(Docker\API\Model\ImageSummary)#991 (10) { ["id":protected]=> string(71) "sha256:16508e5c265dcb5c05017a2a8a8228ae12b7b56b2cda0197ed5411bda200a961" ["parentId":protected]=> string(0) "" ["repoTags":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "ubuntu:18.04" } ["repoDigests":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(78) "ubuntu@sha256:72f832c6184b55569be1cd9043e4a80055d55873417ea792d989441f207dd2c7" } ["created":protected]=> int(1534958937) ["size":protected]=> int(84117621) ["sharedSize":protected]=> int(-1) ["virtualSize":protected]=> int(84117621) ["labels":protected]=> NULL ["containers":protected]=> int(-1) } }
```

I have tried nesting for loops but always hit the same error, I have had some success with populating a new var in the controller and using get methods to populate an array e.g.

```
public function index()
{
  $docker = Docker::create();
  $params=array("all"=>true);
  $images = $docker->imageList($params);
  foreach ($images as $image) {
  $imagestatus[$image->getId()]=$image->getrepoTags();
  }
  return view('admin/images.index', compact ('imagestatus'));
}
```

In this instance i can get the vars from imagestatus.

So questions would be, is it possible to access the protected docker image values from the blade i.e the first controller example?. If its not, why (i'm missing understanding here :).

How can populate and array with all the same values. My second controller example I'm struggling to populate with more than a key and single value. Thanks for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` property is what they call `protected`. When a property is `protected` (rather than `public`) it cannot be accessed directly from outside the object.

This is done for a reason called "information hiding", which is central to object-oriented programming. The main reasoning behind this is that one ought to be able to reason about an object in terms of its behaviour, rather than its implementation.

In your case, you're probably looking for a slightly less philosophical answer, so you could also simply use this:

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
    {{$image->getId()}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, I cant believe that was it. I was using getId in the controller to populate an array but must not have tried it in the blade. Testing it, it does indeed show the id value.

Comment: Sorry one more question, how can I iterate that to allow access to the repotags contained within the var dump. Changing to {{$image->getrepoTags}} I get an :

    htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/admin/images/index.blade.php)

Comment: You can simply use the same concapt again, eg. `@foreach ($image->getrepoTags() as $tag)`

Comment: PS the dollar signs aren't required in twig, you can drop them if you feel like.

Comment: Ok, yep I see now. Its nested within the original for loop. Thanks again Stratadox.